# R - error creating a violin boxplot for one raster

Tags: r, raster, violin-plot, rastervis

I'm trying to create a violin plot for a single raster (initially in GTiff).

Using the library rasterVis, the code should be very simple:

```r
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

rast <- raster("Temperate_WWR.tif")
bwplot(rast)
```

The code returns the error:

> Error in UseMethod("bwplot"):  no applicable method for 'bwplot' applied to an object of class "c('RasterLayer', 'Raster', 'BasicRaster')"

I don't get it...the method applicable for bwplot states that a single raster layer is a legit argument...

Any guess?

Comment: `bwplot` is also the name of the original function in the `lattice` package - do you get the same error if you use `rasterVis::bwplot(rast)`?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not change anything...

Comment: Without more information it might be hard to help you - the error you are getting is generic, so it could be caused by many things. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?